# VS2008 debug, console opens then closes immediately

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, console

I have tried numerous approaches to stop the console from closing - breakpoints, pause and listener functions, sample code, and requests for help on another forum; still no solution. except, if I use a new project, then the console stays open.

My intuition is that this is related to a solution I implemented in an iterator header. The code compiles. My hope is that there is a setting in the VS2008 (same behavior in VS2005) that I should change. what is strange is that I commented out all my code and left a test section with a breakpoints, and still the console closes. "start without debugging" opens the console but does not display the test text.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Automating from Model and Sensor Data" << endl << endl;

    while (true) {
        int choice = GetMenuChoice();
        if (choice == 0) break;
        //DoMenuChoice(lex, choice);
    }

    return 0; //goodbye!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was related to the entry point to the program in main.cpp - rather than a main() function it must be a more elaborate entry function.

see the details here
[LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247699/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmaincrtstar)

Answer (score 0):

On the visual studio menu, have you checked  `Debug > Options`?

It should open the options dialog, at the left side of the dialog, click on `Debugging` and see if there's something that doesn't look right in the settings.

Comment: I found it under tools/options and check 'show all settings'; I unchecked 'break all processes when one process breaks' - still opens then closes. It has been a few years since I last wrote code but I don't remember the console being an issue.

Comment: Also, the way this program is written it prints a menu then loops continually looking for a keypunch selecting a menu option.

Comment: I tried the windows form template but that looks like a deadend - at least it is open.

Comment: solved: used a consul window type and then selected empty project