# unresolved external symbol main referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, sdl, glew

```
    Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in  
    function __tmainCRTStartup  C:\Users\JRFerrell\Desktop\3D dev - VBO 
    set-up\Tutorial\build\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)   Tutorial
```

What do I need to do to correct this unresolved symbol?

Comment: This question is probably off-topic because it is related with general programming.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the main() function of your project is missing or has incorrect syntax. [See this answer in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247699/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmaincrtstar).

Answer (score 0):

SDL (used to?) provide a library called SDLmain on windows, you may need to link to that. Check out http://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows

Comment: Turns out dsilva was correct. Needed to use "wmain" instead of "_tmain" since my project default is in Unicode format. The "_tmain" function is meant to handle either Unicode or ANSI, but for some reason, in this particular case it is not.