# C++ compile error (LNK1120 and LNK2019) with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013, logitech

I am a newbie to C++ and I need help with a very basic program.

**Background information:**
I recently got the Logitech [G19s](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-ch/product/g19s-lcd-gaming-keyboard). It has a small color LCD screen. You can write apps for it in C++. So I decided to try it out, even though I'm new to C++, and write some hello world. Shouldn't be to dificult, but it turns out to be a real pain!

**Problem:**
When I compile my small Hello World app, I get 2 errors: LNK1120 and LNK2019, without any other information. Here's my code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "LogitechLcd.lib")
#include "LogitechLcd.h"

int main() {
    LogiLcdInit(L"Hello World", LOGI_LCD_TYPE_COLOR);
    while (true) {
        LogiLcdUpdate();
        LogiLcdColorSetText(4, L"Hello G19s", 255, 0, 0);
    }
    LogiLcdShutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the [LogitechLcd.h (pastebin.com)](http://pastebin.com/9dcqfBsb).

When I compile this (with Visual Studio Professional 2013), I get the errors mentioned above. Can anyone help me out (and, if possible, explain why it doesn't work)?

**EDIT:**
I somewhat got it to work now! Viusal Studio didn't find the lib, so I had to place it in the project folder. Very stupid mistake!

Comment: Those are no compiler errors, but linker errors (LNK = LINKER or LINK). Make sure the file `LogitechLcd.lib` can be found.

Comment: Don't make us guess at the errors.

Comment: Please copy the exact output.  These are errors from the linker.  It can't find symbols.  You are probably not passing the path to the library to the linker.

Comment: ok, here's the exact output:

Comment: Fehler 2 error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste Externe E:\Freizeit\Programmieren\G19s\thisWillWork\Debug\thisWillWork.exe 1 1 thisWillWork
Fehler 1 error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_WinMain@16" in Funktion "___tmainCRTStartup". E:\Freizeit\Programmieren\G19s\thisWillWork\thisWillWork\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) thisWillWork


-yes, I'm german!

Comment: This is related to [undefined reference to `WinMain@16'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16). Maybe the answer there helps.

Comment: As statet in the edit, i finally got it working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have the project set up as the wrong type.

Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b83e4884-9dec-4d67-ab92-90d5b6c8c51c/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in-function-tmaincrtstartup?forum=Vsexpressvc).

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247699/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmaincrtstar).

Comment: My project is set up as a win32-Application, and if I'm not totally mistaken this means its native c++
PS: The compiler is set to 32 bit as well

Answer (score 1):

Is it a console project? (If you don't know, look at *Project Properties* > *Linker* > *System* > *Subsystem*). It should be the first thing that comes up. If so, make your main function a `wmain` function. If it's a Win32 project it was something like `WinMain(16)`, not sure.

I hope it helped.

Comment: In case you missed it, the OP typed in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870676/c-compile-error-lnk1120-and-lnk2019-with-visual-studio/46133902#comment31381733_20870676): "_As statet in the edit, i finally got it working_"  Jan 3 '14 at 14:52