# C++ MS visual studio error " referenced in function public: void __thiscall ..."

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I get the following error trying to run C++ project in VS

**My main.cpp (ATM machine.cpp)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;

class options
{
    private:
        char user_chose;
        int id;
        int pass;

    public: 

        void login()
        {
            // Get credentials
            cout << "Please enter your user id: ";
            cin >> id;
            cout << "Please enter your password: ";
            cin >> pass;

        }

        void quit()
        {
            cout << "quiting...";
        }

        void IntroMenu()
        {
            cout << "Please select an option from the menu below :" << endl;
            cout << "l -> Login" << endl;
            cout << "c -> Create New Account" << endl;
            cout << "q -> Quit" << endl;
            cout << "> ";
            cin >> user_chose;

            switch (user_chose)
            {
                case ('l'):
                case ('L'):
                    login();
                    break;

                case ('c'):
                case ('C'):

                    Account i;
                    i.createAccount();
                    break;

                case ('q'):
                case ('Q'):
                    quit();
                    break;

                default:
                {
                    cout << "\n***Invalid option***\n" << endl;
                    IntroMenu(); //Recall function
                }
            };
        };
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hi!Welcome to the ATM Machine!" << endl;
    options start;
    start.IntroMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

**My header (Account.h)**

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H_INCLUDED
#define ACCOUNT_H_INCLUDED

class Account
{
    public:
        void createAccount();
};

#endif
```

**(Account.cpp)**

```
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;

Account::createAccount();
void Account::createAccount() 
{
    //Save account on database(txt file)

    cout << "\nAccount created successfully\n" << endl;
}
```

***Error 1***

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall
>   Account::createAccount(void)" (?createAccount@Account@@QAEXXZ)
>   referenced in function "public: void __thiscall
>   options::IntroMenu(void)" (?IntroMenu@options@@QAEXXZ)

***Error 2***

> LNK1120   1 unresolved externals

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Account::createAccount();` this is a syntax error.  Since the compiler doesn't show it, your Account.cpp is not added to the VS project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cpp file:

```
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;


Account::createAccount(); // remove this


void Account::createAccount() 
{
    cout << "\nAccount created successfully\n" << endl;
}
```

After removing that line your program should run.

**EDIT**

After that fix it works fine for me.

You can try to move

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

to`Account.h` and removing the others `using namespace std;`, leaving only `#include <Account.h>` in `main()`.

This hints to missing libraries, so check also if the `Account` class files are in the project root directory.

If that doesn't solve it take a look at [C++ compile error (LNK1120 and LNK2019) with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870676/c-compile-error-lnk1120-and-lnk2019-with-visual-studio/46133902#comment31381733_20870676).

Comment: @OfficialAhmed I added some more details to my answer.

Comment: I used code blocks instead of visual studio and everything works fine .thank you anyway

Comment: @OfficialAhmed I'm glad you were able to solve it one way or the other, it's a strange thing since I ran your code in mine and it ran fine, maybe it's some configurantion isue or dependency absence, but if your satisfied with codeblocks there is no need to lose more time trying to figure out what the problem is.