# Irrlicht LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__createDevice referenced in function _main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, irrlicht

I am trying to build the example [01.HelloWorld" of Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/example001.html) using VS 2010. When I do I get the error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__createDevice referenced in function _main

I found a [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247699/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmaincrtstar) for this problem, and tried to apply some solutions in the answer, by changing  `int main` to `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` and `int _tmain()` but it didn't work.

```
#include <irrlicht.h>

using namespace irr;

using namespace core;
using namespace scene;
using namespace video;
using namespace io;
using namespace gui;

#ifdef _IRR_WINDOWS_
#pragma comment(lib, "Irrlicht.lib")
#pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
#endif
#include <tchar.h>

int main()
{
    IrrlichtDevice *device =
        createDevice( video::EDT_SOFTWARE, dimension2d<u32>(640, 480), 16,
            false, false, false, 0);

    if (!device)
        return 1;

    device->setWindowCaption(L"Hello World! - Irrlicht Engine Demo");

    IVideoDriver* driver = device->getVideoDriver();
    ISceneManager* smgr = device->getSceneManager();
    IGUIEnvironment* guienv = device->getGUIEnvironment();

    guienv->addStaticText(L"Hello World! This is the Irrlicht Software renderer!",
        rect<s32>(10,10,260,22), true);

    IAnimatedMesh* mesh = smgr->getMesh("../../media/sydney.md2");
    if (!mesh)
    {
        device->drop();
        return 1;
    }
    IAnimatedMeshSceneNode* node = smgr->addAnimatedMeshSceneNode( mesh );

    if (node)
    {
        node->setMaterialFlag(EMF_LIGHTING, false);
        node->setMD2Animation(scene::EMAT_STAND);
        node->setMaterialTexture( 0, driver->getTexture("../../media/sydney.bmp") );
    }

    smgr->addCameraSceneNode(0, vector3df(0,30,-40), vector3df(0,5,0));

    while(device->run())
    {
        driver->beginScene(true, true, SColor(255,100,101,140));

        smgr->drawAll();
        guienv->drawAll();

        driver->endScene();
    }

    device->drop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the results of running `dumpbin /symbols Irrlicht.lib | grep createDevice` into the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just on what you've provided, there are three likely solutions:

1. You didn't add lib/VisualStudio to your additional linker directories.
2. IrrLicht.dll is missing from the project directory.
3. The code is looking for `_main()`, not `main()`, and not `_tmain()`.  Try changing `int main()` to `int _main()`.

This probably won't work, but it's the best I can do working on what I've got.

Comment: Thank you! I looked for this solution, and adding the path to C:\bin\irrlicht-1.8.1\lib\Win32-visualstudio did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was adding

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma comment(lib, "Irrlicht.lib")
#endif
```