# Migrating from Visual C++ 2012, 2013 to VSC++ 2015 Unresolved token, symbols

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, onvif

I am trying to reuse a player module of [ONVIF Device Manager](https://sourceforge.net/p/onvifdm/code/HEAD/tree/branches/). The player is built from four projects (***live555, odm.player.lib, odm.player.media, odm.player.host, odm.player.net, odm.player.host***). It was built successfully in Visual Studio 2012 & 2013. When I try to build **odm.player.host** project on VS 2015. It occurs many errors which belong to a class of "unresolved external symbol".

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void * __cdecl memcpy
LNK1120 105 unresolved externals    odm.player.net  
LNK2020 unresolved token (0A00054F) "extern "C" int __cdecl _CrtDbgReportW(
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vfprintf   odm.player.net  
LNK2028 unresolved token (0A000591) "extern "C" void __cdecl __CxxUnregisterExceptionObject
```

There have many answers for the unresolved external symbol problems such as [Unresolved External symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32334000/unresolved-external-symbol-c-vs-2015) or [What is an undefined reference/unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). I first try to follow those answer but I could not solve my problem. Then, I found [another one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ko-KR/5150eeec-4427-440f-ab19-aecb26113d31/updated-to-vs-2015-and-now-get-unresolved-external-errors?forum=vcgeneral) which addressed "*a number of breaking changes in VS2015*" in [Visual C++ change history 2003 - 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-change-history-2003-2015?view=vs-2017).

Again, I tried to follow their answer but still, I could not solve the building problem.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: You need to retarget your solution to the latest SDK and do a clean rebuild.

Comment: @Mgetz, I have tried your suggestion, but I could not solve it. Do you have another solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the LNK2020 error, go to Project `Properties` > `C/C++` > `Code Generation` and change the `Debug` configuration's `Runtime Library` setting from `Multi-Threaded (/MT)` or `Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)` to `Multi-Threaded Debug (/MTd)` or `Multi-Threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`.

I don't know why VS2015 doesn't choose the Debug settings for the Debug configuration by default, but there you have it.